# Getting the uid instead of the pid with profile2

Tags: users

I would like a function that allows me to have the same uid and pid with profile2 for each user but I don't know how I can do that.
I'm trying to make a function which allows me to return a list of users according to certain criterias. For exemple, user A, B and C each has can choose one color among a list of colors. User A and B choose the red color and User C choose Blue. The entity id for this criteria is the same as the profile2 pid. After that I get back the list of users with the function user_load_multiple($userlist) and then show the list but it shows the list according the uid and not the pid and that's what I want to change. Sorry for my poor english.